# Cloud Connect Configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, marketing-cloud-connect

Wondering if it may be possible to practice configuring Marketing connect when I dont have a Marketing and Sales Cloud Account Sandbox to experiment on?

Comment: Nope. Closest you can 'experiment' is a Trailhead program - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFMC does not have any developer edition so you would be unable to fully complete the integration. However you could do some steps with SFDC in their DEV org

There is this '[Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect)'